# Error in changing a vertex style

Tags: java, jgrapht, jgraphx, jgraph

I am trying to change the style of a vertex v4 with the following code. I get error though with changing the style. I have tried to do other actions instead like setVisible(false) and it works. So it must be the method that I am using. What should I change?

```
           public class graphgen extends JFrame {

                JFrame frame ;
                static JGraph jgraph ;

                final static mxGraph graph = new mxGraph() {


                final static mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);

                Object cell ;
                Object v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, w9, w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, z1, z2, z3, z4, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6 ;

                private static final int OPACITY_PALE = 20;
                private static final int OPACITY_HL = 100;


                public graphgen() {



                    gen();

                }

                public void gen(){

                Hashtable<String, Object> oldstyle = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
                oldstyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_OPACITY, OPACITY_PALE);
                ....

                Hashtable<String, Object> newstyle = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
                newstyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_OPACITY, OPACITY_HL);
                ...


stylesheet.putCellStyle( oldstyle, oldstyle);
    stylesheet.putCellStyle( newstyle, newstyle);

Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                    try
                    {....

    Object v4 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "label", 380, 80, 80,
                    30, oldstyle);
                ...

                if (GC.contains("aaa")) {

                            graph.getView().getState(v4).setStyle(newstyle);

                            graphComponent.refresh();
                            graph.repaint();
                    }

                ....}
                    finally
                    {
                        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                    }



            getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
            add(graphComponent);

            ...
        }

            public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                        graphgen frame = new graphgen();

                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setSize(1600, 1200);
                    frame.setVisible(true);


                }
            }
```

I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at graphgen.gen(graphgen.java:482) // line with raph.getView().getState(v4).changeStyle(newstyle);
```

Comment: It would be easier to tell what exactly is `null` if you did not chain that many methods together.

Comment: There are 3 things that can be `null` on that line: `graph`, return value of `getView()`, and return value of `getState(v4)`. The first is unlikely, unless you have reassigned `graph` after the `getModel()` call. Using temporary variables to store the values would help checking which of those is causing the problem.

Comment: getstate(v4) is null but dont get why @kiheru

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mxGraph.setCellStyle(String style, Object[] cells)
```

instead.

Comment: Have tried it. Not working. Anyway i found a different solution, not the most efficient but still does my job. With continuing ifs for each vertex inserted.